# How to use the new affix plugin in twitter's bootstrap 2.1.0?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

The bootstrap documentation on that topic is a little confusing to me. I want to achieve similar behaviour like in the docs with the affix navbar: The navbar is below a paragraph / page heading, and upon scrolling down it should first scroll along until reaching the top of the page, and then stick there fixed for further scrolldowns.

As jsFiddle does not work with the navbar concept, I've set up a separate page for usage as a minimal example: http://i08fs1.ira.uka.de/~s_drr/navbar.html

I use this as my navbar:

```
<div class="navbar affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span12">
                <a class="brand" href="#">My Brand</a> 
                This is my navbar.
             </div>
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </div> <!-- navbar-inner -->
</div> <!-- navbar -->
```

I thinkg i would want `data-offset-top` to be of value 0 (since the bar should "stick" to the very top" but with 50 there is at least some effect watchable.

If also put the javascript code in place:

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready (function (){
            $(".navbar").affix ();
        });
     </script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to use affix() on the main nav-bar of your page?

Comment: @NithinEmmanuel yes, see the javascript in the post or at the sample: http://i08fs1.ira.uka.de/~s_drr/navbar.html

Comment: why don't you use use `.navbar-fixed-top` instead of using affix()?

Comment: @NithinEmmanuel because thats not what i want. `.navbar-fixed-top`would place the navbar to the top **all the time**. I want a page header ABOVE the navbar, and when scrolling down (and thus the navbar would bet scrolled away) it should stick to the top - then and only then. Bootstrap docs used the very same mechanisms as a subnav in their previous docs, sadly they have removed it for the 2.1.0 docs.

Comment: For one the nesting of your Javascript is incorrect. `)};` should be `});`

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I was having a similar problem, and I believe I found an improved solution.

Don't bother specifying `data-offset-top` in your HTML. Instead, specify it when you call `.affix()`:

```
$('#nav').affix({
    offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
});​
```

The advantage here is that you can change the layout of your site without needing to update the `data-offset-top` attribute. Since this uses the actual computed position of the element, it also prevents inconsistencies with browsers that render the element at a slightly different position.

---

You will still need to clamp the element to the top with CSS. Furthermore, I had to set `width: 100%` on the nav element since `.nav` elements with `position: fixed` misbehave for some reason:

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

One last thing: When an affixed element becomes fixed, its element no longer takes up space on the page, resulting in the elements below it to "jump". To prevent this ugliness, I wrap the navbar in a `div` whose height I set to be equal to the navbar at runtime:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav" class="navbar">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
$('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
```

---

[Here's the obligatory jsFiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/Uaa3U/).

Comment: Great tip to remove the "jump" - completely overlooked the fact that this item gets removed and thought my issue was contained in the affix/js portion of my code.

Comment: This answer is the best! Everything works as it should. The 'jump' part was the one missing in most tutorials I found. Thanks!

Comment: One important correction: Use offset() instead of position() in your jquery code in your first code snippet.  Explanation: The position() function gives you the offset within the parent element, but offset() is its position within the document, which is what you actually want (yeah, the names are counter-intuitive).  So your code wouldn't work if your affix element is inside another element.  You should also only pass the "top" value like this: $("#nav").affix({ offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top.  And it should be inside a ready() block so you know the page layout is complete.

Comment: Nice! Works perfectly and it's very smooth. By the way, I'm looking for the same example with a sticky footer. If you know how to do that, can you update the jsFiddle? Thanks!

Comment: @Jocelyn -- Shouldn't be much different -- you'll want to change all instances of "top" to "bottom" in the JS, and in the css do `bottom: 100%;` to stick it to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Jocelyn -- Erp, that wont work. It'd have to be `bottom: 0;` and you'll need to set `margin-bottom: 0;` as well. But I'm not really sure how you want it to behave; a sticky footer is kind of a strange concept.

Comment: @Jocelyn.  You can download the sticky-footer-navbar.css from bootstrap and then simply add a #footer to the bottom of the page, after the last container close.      
     <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: @namuol.. Great work on the script. I have it implemented but am having an issue getting a working collapsible nav bar in the nav space. When I attempt to insert some nav code from other examples (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) it seems to not understand what I am trying to do. What needs to be added in your fiddle to make the nav pieces respond to a resize?

Comment: If `#nav` has padding, it's not enough to use `$("#nav").height()` for the wrapper's height. I had to replace it with `$("#nav").outerHeight()`

Comment: How can I do it in bootstrap 4? It doesn't supports affix.

Comment: This answer is quite old. You may want to try using `position: sticky` instead! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 76):

Just implemented this for the first time, and here's what I've found.

The `data-offset-top` value is the amount of pixels that you must scroll in order for the affixing effect to take place. In your case, once `50px` is scrolled, the class on your item is changed from `.affix-top` to `.affix`. You'd probably want to set `data-offset-top` to about `130px` in your use case.

Once this class change occurs, you must position your element in css by styling the positioning for class `.affix`. Bootstrap 2.1 already defines `.affix` as `position: fixed;` so all you need to do is add your own position values.

Example:

```
.affix {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 20px; 
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thx, that somewhat works. I've updated my example page to that. Problem is now, as soon as the navbar gets "affix" as css class, the navbar css class is discarded. but i think that is just a bug/shortcomming from bootstrap. Won't be easy to change without doiing it in LESS and rebuilding bootstrap.

Comment: It looks to me as the `.navbar` class is preserved - are you sure?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I spent ages trying to figure this out

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13151016/742156) for a slightly-improved, more general solution.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this very issue I have modified the affix plugin to emit a jQuery event when an object is affixed or unaffixed.

Here is the pull request: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4712

And the code: https://github.com/corbinu/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-affix.js

And then do this to attach the navbar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#navbar').on('affixed', function () {
        $('#navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top')
    });

    $('#navbar').on('unaffixed', function () {
        $('#navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top')
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `.affix()` from your script.

Bootstrap gives the option of accomplishing things either via `data-attributes` or straight JavaScript most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I've got this from the twitterbootstrap's source code and it's working pretty well:

HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
        <ul id="navbar" class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.bs-docs-sidenav {
    max-height: 340px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 240px;
}
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.bs-docs-sidenav').affix({
            offset: {
                top: function (){
                    return $window.width() <= 980 ? 290 : 210
                }
            }
        })
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the script. Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  #content {
    width: 800px;
    height: 2000px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .menu {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
  .affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div style="height: 200px"></div>

        <div class="affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="180">
            <div class="menu">AFFIX BAR</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to namuol and Dave Kiss for the solution. 
In my case I had a tiny problem with navbar height and width when I used afflix and collapse plugins together. The problem with width can be easily solved inheriting it from parent element (container in my case). Also I could manage to make it collapsing smoothly with a bit of javascript (coffeescript actually). The trick is to set wrapper height to `auto` before collapse toggle occurs and fix it back after.

Markup (haml):

```
#wrapper
  #navbar.navbar
    .navbar-inner
      %a.btn.btn-navbar.btn-collapse
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar

      #menu.nav-collapse
        -# Menu goes here
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: inherit;
}

#navbar {
  &.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
  }
}
```

Coffeescript:

```
class Navigation
  @initialize: ->
    @navbar = $('#navbar')
    @menu = $('#menu')
    @wrapper = $('#wrapper')

    @navbar.affix({offset: @navbar.position()})
    @adjustWrapperHeight(@navbar.height())

    @navbar.find('a.btn-collapse').on 'click', () => @collapse()

    @menu.on 'shown', () => @adjustWrapperHeight(@navbar.height())
    @menu.on 'hidden', () => @adjustWrapperHeight(@navbar.height())

  @collapse: ->
    @adjustWrapperHeight("auto")
    @menu.collapse('toggle')

  @adjustWrapperHeight: (height) ->
    @wrapper.css("height", height)

$ ->
  Navigation.initialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for attach the navbar :

```
function affixnolag(){

    $navbar = $('#navbar');
    if($navbar.length < 1)
        return false;

    h_obj = $navbar.height();

    $navbar
        .on('affixed', function(){      
            $navbar.after('<div id="nvfix_tmp" style="height:'+h_obj+'px">');
        })
        .on('unaffixed', function(){
            if($('#nvfix_tmp').length > 0)
                $('#nvfix_tmp').remove();
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer, you can also do something like the following to do everything in one go:

```
$('#nav').affix({
  offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
}).wrap(function() {
  return $('<div></div>', {
    height: $(this).outerHeight()
  });
});​
```

This not only invokes the `affix` plugin, but will also wrap the affixed element in a div which will maintian the original height of the navbar.