# Weird JS error when it comes to a sticky nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a site that you can see [here](http://homegrowndevelopment.com/).  I have an issue with my sticky nav bar, as is, it flickers when I scroll to the bottom of the page.

When my JS is this, it work does not flicker:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
        $('#nav').affix({
            offset: 675
        });
    });
</script>
```

but the nav bar jumps violently around.  However when the nav bar is this, it does not jump around, but it does flicker...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
        $('#nav').affix({
            offset: $('#nav').height()
        });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously, I want a nav bar that does not flicker or jump.  I'm checked my code on FireFox, Chrome, and Safari.  Please help me!

Comment: Please post a small code sample to reproduce, otherwise this question will not be of much use to anyone else.

Comment: People don't want to read whole of your html page. You can make the problem easily detectable by making a small example.

Comment: Is the `affix` plugin changing the `position` of the navigation bar to `fixed`?

Comment: hey brian i answered your question earlier.. please let me know if it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**quick answer:** just assign the same css properties you applied to #nav.affix to #nav.affix-bottom ie in homegrown.css change

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

to

```
#nav.affix, #nav.affix-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

**explanation:** most of the explanation is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082615/766570) post. But based on my testing i noticed that as you where scrolling near the end of the page.. the flickering was happening b/c `.affix-bottom` was being applied in bursts to your `#nav` div.. so i simply gave `.affix-bottom` the same properties of `.affix`.. so that no abrupt change happens to the div.. hope this helps!

Comment: Hey it's a pleasure! Great looking site btw.. And nice name :)