# Bootstrap, make a navbar sticky after scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar which is below the header image. I want the navbar to stick to the top of the webpage when I scroll down. I can't think of the jQuery or CSS required, because the navbar seems to stick right below the header image leaving some gap.

```
<div class="headerwrap pull-center">
<div  class="container">
    <div id="header" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span5" id="phones">
            <img class="phone" src="img/white.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="span7" id="mm-logo">
            <img class="mm-log" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="navbar navbar-inner" id="border-stuff">
    <div class="span12">

        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>

<!-- Everything you want hidden at 768px or less, place within here -->
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" id="center-nav">
<ul class="nav" >
    <li><a href="#h1"><h3>Heading1</h3></a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li>
    <li><a href="#h2"><h3>Heading2</h3></a></li><li      class="divider-vertical"></li>
    <li><a href="#h3"><h3>Heading3</h3></a></li><li class="divider-vertical">  </li>
    <li><a href="#h4"><h3>Heading4</h3></a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li>
    <li><a href="#h5"><h3>Heading4</h3></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be nice if you had a jsfiddle..

Answer (score 20):

If you want your navbar to stay fixed at the top of the screen only once the header image has scrolled away you can use [the bootstrap affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Comment: I could not get the affix plugin to work in a navbar as most tutorials show it being used as a side navbar. Could you help me with making a top navbar using the affix plugin?

Comment: For an example check out the jsFiddle in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070970/how-to-use-the-new-affix-plugin-in-twitters-bootstrap-2-1-0/13151016#13151016

Answer (score 4):

You just need to replace your Jquery code to this:

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 50
  }
});
```

And adjust the top to whatever fits best.