# Trouble with nav-justified in Bootstrap 3.0 on responsive devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I am using the Bootstrap 3.0 framework and Modern Business theme (http://startbootstrap.com/modern-business). When using the default Modern Business nav settings, the main menu dropdowns work brilliantly as they should on mobile devices. However, when I change the menu to be "nav-justified" in the HTML code (using Bootstrap's "nav-justified" CSS class), the menu does not work as expected.

When you tap any menu item with dropdowns, it shows a navigation dropdown on the far left side, which runs outside of the parent CSS frame:

[image: Navigation Error]

I am also using the Sticky Nav solution found here: [How to use the new affix plugin in twitter's bootstrap 2.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070970/how-to-use-the-new-affix-plugin-in-twitters-bootstrap-2-1-0/13151016#13151016)

Here is my HTML code for the menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="nav" class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
                        </div> <!-- navbar-header -->

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                          <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div> <!-- collapse -->
                    </div> <!-- span12 -->
                </div> <!-- container -->
            </div> <!-- navbar-inner -->
        </div> <!-- navbar -->
    </div> <!-- nav-wrapper -->
  </nav>
```

And here is the script I have at the bottom of my HTML:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

  $('#nav').affix({
      offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
  });
});
</script>
```

Here, also, is the obligatory JSFiddle to examine (JS and CSS code linked in the JSFiddle panel on the left): http://jsfiddle.net/L94Mj/

I'm sure I'm somehow dancing around the answer, but this thing has had me stumped for two days now, and I need a fresh brain to look at things. I'm happy to provide whatever extra code is needed to help find the answer.