# Affix element in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, affix

Today I learned about affix and the use of it with Bootstrap. I read all about it on the Bootstrap website and stack-overflow, and eventually checked [How to use the new affix plugin in twitter's bootstrap 2.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070970/how-to-use-the-new-affix-plugin-in-twitters-bootstrap-2-1-0) (see the jsfiddle link) as a good example.

But, I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I added the right javascript to my index.php. I added the CSS to my stylesheet and just copy-pasted the nav-bar example from jsfiddle into my index.php. Nothing works.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- micro hero unit-->
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="well">
                 <h1> Some page title </h1> 
                <p>This is a website.</p>
                <p> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Tell me more</a> 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: $('#nav').offset().top
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3.0 or 2+? And we need to see some code to help you...

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.

Comment: So a Bootstrap 2.1 guide will not suffice for a Bootstrap 3.0 build.. In other terms, you need to find a tutorial that will show you how to do what you want, but with Boostrap 3+ - You could start here: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-affix.php

Comment: How come you are using bootstrap 3 but using span12 which is definitely a bootstrap 2 class?